# error: function declared 'ms_abi' here was previously declared without calling convention (clang)

Tags: c, clang, abi, osdev, freestanding

when I try to compile C code that includes another C header I get this error:

```
x86_64-uefi/../../libk/string.h:9:10: error: function declared 'ms_abi' here was
      previously declared without calling convention
KABI int memcmp(const void *d1, const void *d2, uint64_t len);
         ^
x86_64-uefi/../../libk/string.h:9:10: note: previous declaration is here
```

The compiler is clang and the involved files are the following:
`memcmp.c`

```
#include "../string.h"

KABI int memcmp(const void *d1, const void *d2, uint64_t len) {
    const uint8_t *d1_ = d1, *d2_ = d2;
    for(uint64_t i = 0; i < len; i += 1, d1_++, d2_++){
        if(*d1_ != *d2_) return *d1_ < *d2_ ? -1 : 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`string.h`

```
#pragma once

#include "systemapi.h"
#include "typedefs.h"

KABI int memcmp(const void *d1, const void *d2, uint64_t len);
```

`systemapi.h` (typedefs just define the uintx_t types)

```
#pragma once

#define KABI __attribute__((ms_abi))
```

Another header that includes `string.h`, `libk.h`

```
#pragma once

#include "string.h"
#include "systemapi.h"
#include "typedefs.h"
```

And the file that includes lib.h and that reports the error when compiling, `main.c` (but all files report the error when linking with `lib.h`)

```
KABI void arch_main(void)
{
     // The function does not uses memcmp, just uses the KABI part of lib.h
     // Calling the whole lib.h is a convention 

}
```

Flags of the compiler: `-I/usr/include/efi -I/usr/include/efi/x86_64 -I/usr/include/efi/protocol -fno-stack-protector -fpic -fshort-wchar -mno-red-zone -DHAVE_USE_MS_ABI -c main.c -o main.o`

Comment: @MichaelPetch I changed the order but nothing changed, same error message

Comment: I created a branch in my github project so you can see this with more context: https://github.com/TheStr3ak5/CKA/tree/TheStr3ak5-newABI, just build this branch following the BUILD file and you will see the errors.

Comment: @MichaelPetch yeah you are right, it solved my issues, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without having your build environment, an educated guess would be that you are redefining the built in functions that have prototypes that are incompatible with the `ms_abi` function attribute. If you are compiling with `-ffreestanding` and supplying your own functions like `memcpy`, `memset`, etc., you should consider compiling with `-fno-builtin` option so that CLANG/GCC doesn't use its built in forms of the functions that may conflict with your own.